# bool return many values

Tags: c++, function, return, boolean

I am trying to return multiple values from a bool function, but I get an "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. My code is

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std; 

bool te(int b,int *c,int *e){

    if (b>5){
        *c=68;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        *e=69;
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    int  y;
    int *z;
    int *r;

    cout<<"Give number:"<<endl;
    cin>>y;

    if(te(y,z,r)==1) {
        cout<<"b is >5"<<endl;
        cout<<*z<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"b is <5"<<endl;
        cout<<*r<<endl;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

It works if the bool=false, but i get the segmentation fault when bool=true.

Comment: Use references or return `std::tuple`. Or your custom object.

Answer (score 1):

You are using pointers without allocating actual physical memory.
you should do something like:

```
int y, z, r;
```

and then

```
if (te(y, &z, &r)) ...
```